# Folders and metadata filter

Tags: 2013, office-365, folder, metadata

Is it possible to keep folders in view, no matter what filter  I use on metadata filter in a document library?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set view filter to show items with filter setting `Content Type` equal to `Folder` at the end of your filter like this:

```
.... (any other your filter settings)....
OR 
Content Type 
equals 
Folder
```

Comment: This helped with showing folders in my different views, but the folders is still being filtered out when I use any kind of filter method

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. Try to add this filter pair `OR Content Type equals Folder` to the end of your filter. View updated answer.